# Preloader showing only once per visit

Tags: javascript

I have a question about a preloader i made. The preloader is showing everytime when someone goes to the page, but i want it to be shown only once per visit.

My javascript is very basic:

```
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementsByClassName('kmade-preloader')[0].classList.add('loaded');
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementsByClassName('kmade-preloader')[0].style.display = 'none';
    }, 4000);

    if (!sessionStorage.getItem('doNotShow')) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('doNotShow', true);
        Preloader();
    } else {
        $('.kmade-preloader, .kmade-preloader').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work with this code?

Comment: I'd normally consider that when someone "goes to the page" that means the same thing as visiting the page. What exactly do you mean by "per visit" if going to your web page isn't always supposed to count as a separate visit?

Comment: You may want to store the details of last visit on using localStorage API and apply logic to show or not.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage